# Code duplication: how to avoid in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-fragment

Expectation: if the flag is true, then empty div "container" around div "content"

```
const Demo = () => {
   const [flagABC] = useFlagFeature(true)
   return (
     <div className="featureflagoff"> style= {} onMouseEnter = {}  //if feature flag is off || if feature flag is ON then empty div  
       <div className="content">           
          // huge code
       <div>
     </div>
   );
}
```

how can i avoid copying the  ("huge code") twice.

Comment: Lazy load the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the `huge code` to a variable and reference it.

```
const hugeCode = <div>...</div>

return (
  <div className="featureflagoff">
    <div className="content">           
      {hugeCode}
    <div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `flagABC` is the flag, you can do something like this:

```
const Demo = () => {
   const [flagABC] = useFlagFeature(true)
   return (
     <div className={flagABC ? "" : "featureflagoff"}>
       <div className="content">           
          // huge code
       <div>
     </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: my mistake. i forgot to add style and onMouseEnter in that div. so i think this solution wont work as i see i dnt want just the condition check for className instead the complete attributes.

Comment: Even for the onMounseEnter function, you can simply check the flag and trigger it accordingly. And you can do the same for the styles.